# Dependency Injection for Sitecore pipeline processor

Tags: pipelines, dependency-injection

We are using Castel windsor for DI in our Sitecore solution. Though we haven't done any IOC registration using Sitecore pipelines, It still resolves the Controllers. I'm fine with it. But the same is not working for Pipeline processors,

for ex:

```
Public class MyPipelineClass
{
    private IMyDependency myDependency;

    public MyPilelineClass(IMyDependency _myDependency){
        this.myDependency = _myDependency;
    }

    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
         myDependency.Execute();
     }
}
```

How can I achieve this sort of injecting dependencies to constructor of sitecore pipeline processor from Windsor container?

I'm ready to provide any specific details that'll help answering this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're running Sitecore 8.2 or later, you can add `resolve="true"` to the `<pipeline>` element to enable DI resolution for the processor.

[Sitecore uses `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` for dependency injection](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection), which [doesn't appear to list Windsor as a supported container](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection). It may be possible, but I'd seriously consider whether Windsor offers features/performance that make it worth it for your project to go "off the beaten path".

Comment: So, do you suggest using Microsoft.Extenstions.DependencyInjection for resolving pipelines, alongside using Castle Windsor for resolving Controllers??

Comment: Controllers are automatically resolved using `Microsoft.Extenstions.DependencyInjection` by default. However, I believe the default container requires registration (ie. it won't look at a controller's ctor arguments unless you register it)

Comment: Ok.. let me try this.

Comment: I've ended up using castle for controllers(will plan to change this to use sitecore dependency injestionl later) and Microft.Extensions.DependencyInjection for Sitecore pipelines for now...  Thank you, Richard.